# How to move some basic CSS styling to an external stylesheet

Tags: html, css

For a university project, I am creating a basic website. I used in-line styling to create the website but recently the subject coordinator changed the requirements so that we are only permitted to use an external CSS stylesheet. I've transferred most of my project across but I'm struggling with this div section (attached).

How can I convert this CSS styling so that it fits nicely into my CSS stylesheet. I'm not a coding expert by any means but it seems that maybe the multiple div entries in my CSS are overriding each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a class attribute to the div

```
<div class="my_class_name">
    <h1>Welcome to the Websystems</h1>
</div>
```

Now, In your external stylesheet add the following CSS

```
.my_class_name
{
    background-color:#000000;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)? There are a lot of ways to do this.

You can use a `class` or `id` to do this. You can set a `class` name for your div and in your css file style that div like this:

#### HTML

```
<div class="your-class-name">
    <h1>Welcome to the WebSystem</h1>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.your-class-name {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```